# Excel VBA does not respond after running a macro with a loop

Tags: excel, vba

this is my first post after endless attempt for 2 weeks straight.

So I have these mega Excel files, with almost 600 000 lines. 
I have to calculate the average of certain values in my sheet (under certain conditions), while looping through a column (second one). 
I have to loop my program with a while loop for at least 630 000 times. 
Except when I launch the macro, it automatically says: Excel does not respond .. and it stays like this for hours. The longest period of time I let it run was 11 hours without touching anything... I was still not responding ...
Funny thing is: when I reduce the amount of looping just to test, it is extremely fast when I do it for 10 000 times but it gets blocked again around 35 000.

Here is my code:

```
  Dim rw As Long
  Dim erw As Long
  rw = 3
  erw = 631000
  Dim r As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim somme As Long
    For r = 1 To 200
      i = 0
      somme = 0
      Do While rw < erw
        If IsNumeric(Cells(rw, 7)) = True Then
          If Cells(rw, 2) = r And Cells(rw, 7) <> 0 Then
            c = Cells(rw, 7).Value
            somme = somme + c
            i = i + 1
        End If
        rw = rw + 1
      End If
    Loop
    If i <> 0 Then
      Cells(r + 2, 8).Value = somme / i
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

I did try to add the following after suggestions in this site:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False
ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
```

But it still was not working. If anyone can help me with it, I'd be extremely grateful. This is my first VBA code, and I know I can do it without a Macro, but my boss insists on me doing it this way...

Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you have an example or can give us more information about the data (expecially in column 7 and 2)?

Comment: You conditions for each rows are: 1) in column 2 value is between 1 and 200; 2) in column 7 the value is numeric and not 0. Then of these rows you want an average of the value in column 7 for each value of column 2. These averages are to be listed in column 8. Do you confirm? Also: how the averages must be displayed in column 8?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey Yes. The data is actually the recording of data fof a tunneling boring machine. So, in column 1, there is the time of the recording of the data. The data i have is recorded every 20 seconds. The second column represents the position of the machine when it was recorded, it varies from 1 to 200 for this file. Then there is clolum 7 which represents the speed of the machine.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey As you may have understood, I have to calculate the average of the speed (among other data) for every position of the machine, while eliminating the null values, since it represents when the machine stops.

Comment: So you want the average speed of the machine while active for each stages. And i guess there wont be a record for the machine while retreating, correct? The value in column 2 will always increase along the rows. Do you want the average speed specifed in each row? Or do you want just a list with those 200 stages and relative average speed?

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey I want a list with those 200 stages and their relative average speed.

Comment: Why don't your boss want a formula based solution? Can you just use a formula in VBA or do he want a complicated no-formula-whatsoever-solution? Because i would suggest to use a SUM.IFS and if he just don't want to have a formula in the sheet, you might use it via VBA and then copy-paste the values.

Comment: Please always indent your code so you can see the structure easily.  Note that `rw = rw + 1` is inside an `If`.  If the code finds a non-numeric cell, it will loop for ever because the row number is not stepped.  Since you are not finding the last row but using 631,000, I assume the code stops when it hits the first blank line.

Comment: @EvilBlueMonkey What do you mean by formula based solution? No he just want it in VBA, no matter what the code is. In our company, we are not developpers we're engineers in construction, so this is all new to us, and he specifically want to use VBA for i don't know what reason..

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code:

```
Sub SubAverageReport()

    'Declarations.
    Dim RngColumnStages As Range
    Dim RngColumnSpeeds As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim RngResults As Range
    Dim WksWorksheet01 As Worksheet
    Dim BytStage As Byte
    Dim LngCounter01 As Long
    Dim LngDivisor As Long
    Dim LngSpeedsSum As Long

    'Setting variables.
    Set WksWorksheet01 = ActiveSheet
    Set RngColumnStages = WksWorksheet01.Range("B3:B631000")
    Set RngColumnSpeeds = WksWorksheet01.Range("G3:G631000")
    Set RngResults = WksWorksheet01.Range("I3")
    Set RngTarget = RngColumnStages(1, 1)

    'Covering the stages.
    For BytStage = 1 To 200

        'Setting variables.
        LngSpeedsSum = 0
        LngDivisor = 0

        'Covering all the stages recurrence.
        For LngCounter01 = 1 To Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RngColumnStages, BytStage)
            'Setting the RngTarget as the next recurrence of the given stage.
            Set RngTarget = RngColumnStages.Find(What:=BytStage, _
                                            After:=RngTarget, _
                                            LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                            LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                            SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                            MatchCase:=False, _
                                            SearchFormat:=False _
                                           )

            'Checking if the speed is numeric and different from 0.
            If IsNumeric(RngColumnSpeeds(RngTarget.Row - RngColumnStages.Row + 1, 1).Value) And _
               (RngColumnSpeeds(RngTarget.Row - RngColumnStages.Row + 1, 1).Value <> 0) Then
                    'Setting LngSpeedsSum so it sums all the numeric value in RngColumnSpeeds different from 0.
                    LngSpeedsSum = LngSpeedsSum + RngColumnSpeeds(RngTarget.Row - RngColumnStages.Row + 1, 1).Value
                    'Setting LngSpeedsSum so it counts all the numeric value in RngColumnSpeeds different from 0.
                    LngDivisor = LngDivisor + 1
            End If
        Next

        'Reporting stage.
        RngResults.Value = BytStage
        'Checking if any record was found and reporting accordingly.
        If LngDivisor <> 0 Then
            RngResults.Offset(0, 1).Value = LngSpeedsSum / LngDivisor
        Else
            RngResults.Offset(0, 1).Value = "No records"
        End If

        'Setting RngResult for the next result.
        Set RngResults = RngResults.Offset(1, 0)
    Next

End Sub
```

Tell me if it satisfies you, if you have any question or improvements to ask about.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked within seconds!!

here is the new code, that was suggested to me in another forum:

```
Sub AverageMyNumbers()


Dim r, i As Long


r = 3  '' Starting row output data (average result)

i = (r - 1) + 200   '' Last row output data (average result)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Range(Cells(r, "H"), Cells(i, "H")).FormulaR1C1 = _

        "=SUMIFS(R3C7:R631000C7,R3C2:R631000C2,ROW(RC8)-ROW(R2C8))/COUNTIFS(R3C7:R631000C7,""<>0"",R3C2:R631000C2,ROW(RC8)-ROW(R2C8))"


Range(Cells(r, "H"), Cells(i, "H")).Value = Range(Cells(r, "H"), Cells(i, "H")).Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
MsgBox "Job Done"


End Sub
```

Thanks again for your comments and answers.

Comment: Well done. It's basically what i've suggested: using a formula and then copy-pasting it via VBA. I'd give an advise: don't use a single letter name for your variables: it is hard to find and eventually replace them. I'd suggest at least 3 letters and it might be good to add a prefix with the type of variable.